# Molecules in motion and heat

Tags: thermodynamics

If, as it is often said, heat is nothing but molecules in motion, then does the motion of molecules *cause* heat, or does heat first need to be *applied* in order to cause molecules to move?

Another way of asking this question: what causes molecules to bounce around all the time?  Why don't they remain motionless?

Comment: Meaningless question.

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase,

> If A is B, does A cause B or does B cause A?

No. A and B are the same thing. That thing does not cause itself.